# Firebase Admin: Change Provider from facebook to email/password

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I am building a dashboard for a web app I have that uses Firebase, and I am trying to update a user, that was created with Facebook login, to be able to login with email and password With Firebase Admin SDK. I am trying this:

```
    override fun changeIdentityProviderToEmailAndPassword(uid: String, email: String): Completable {
        return Single.fromCallable { auth.getUser(uid) }
            .flatMapCompletable {
                val currentProvider = it.providerData.first()
                val emailProvider = UserProvider.builder()
                    .setProviderId("password")
                    .setUid(email)
                    .setEmail(email)
                    .build()
                val request: UserRecord.UpdateRequest = UserRecord.UpdateRequest(uid)
                    .setProvidersToUnlink(listOf(currentProvider.providerId))
                    .setProviderToLink(emailProvider)
                Completable.fromFuture(auth.updateUserAsync(request))
            }
    }
```

but it is not working and I always gets this error:

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Unexpected HTTP response with status: 400
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But documentation says "password" is the right provider id for login with email and password. Is there a way to do this using Firebase Admin SDK?